# Incorrect DIV formatting when processing SQL request

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently working with a database that contains the following table structure:

```
round | current
===============
P     | 0
1     | 1
2     | 0
3     | 0
4     | 0
A     | 0
```

I have been trying to write PHP code that will output "a lit up circle" for every row in which current is one. So with the table above, 1 would be lit up because current is 1 - the rest of the other rounds would be represented by grey circles.

I've included an example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUgkY.png

However the difficulty I'm having right now is that my code is outputting this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGbkO.png when its only meant to be returning a single row as above.

I've included the HTML output here: http://jsfiddle.net/pn8BW/

This is the PHP/MySQL I'm using now. Would appreciate some help on this because I've been working at it for an hour :-(:

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * from ts_rounds";
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
$circleSize = array ('circle_small', 'circle');
$rounds = '';
foreach ($result as $row) {

    switch ($row['round']) {
        case 'P':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r0" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>P</h3></div>';
        case '1':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r1" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>1</h3></div>';
        case '2':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r2" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>2</h3></div>';
        case '3':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r3" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>3</h3></div>';
        case '4':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r4" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>4</h3></div>';
        case 'A':
            $rounds .=   '<div id="r5" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>A</h3></div>';
    }
}
echo $rounds;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot `break;` in your `switch`:

```
case 'P':
    $rounds .=   '<div id="r0" class="'.$circleSize[$row['current']].'"><h3>P</h3></div>';
    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a `break;` before each subsequent condition test in your `switch`, e.g..

```
    case 'P':
        $rounds .=   ... ;
        break;
    case '1':
        $rounds .=   ... ;
        break;
```

Without a `break;`, the logic flow will "fall through" to the next action.